# Getting network error while sending an API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am sending an API request to: `https://api.chart-img.com/v1/tradingview/advanced-chart?key={API_KEY}`
It also requires a Bearer token in the header which is also included. When I send the call through Postman, I get the expected response. This is my request:

```
const API_KEY = "bbd46466-5c55-427b-aaa7-7a19b6ea7e07";
const API_URL = `https://api.chart-img.com/v1/tradingview/advanced-chart?key=${API_KEY}`;

const Header = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
};

axios.get(API_URL, Header).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

But when I send the call from my code, I receive this error:

[image: The error message]

It is working fine on postman and not in my code, can I assume it is some sort of security issue like CORS?
Any help in this will be appreciated. The link to the documentation is given:

https://doc.chart-img.com/

Comment: "can I assume it is some sort of security issue like CORS" — If it is then there should be a more useful error message (which isn't exposed to your JS code) on the browser dev tools and you should look there to see what it is.

Comment: Then I am lost. I have no idea why the error is occurring. I have tried almost everything but the issue is persisting

Comment: the url your trying (the value of API_URL) will 404, hence the error, you should read the docs and use an endpoint which returns something

Comment: Updated, that gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
axios.get(API_URL, { headers: Headers }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Already tried, same response

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `API_KEY` inside `Authorization` header. Just write it as `API_URL`. As mentioned in documentation.

[image: documentation]

```
const axios = require("axios")
const API_URL = `https://api.chart-img.com/v1/tradingview/advanced-chart?key=XXX`
axios.get(API_URL).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Tried this way too, same error

Answer (score -1):

**The Code**

```
axios.get(API_URL, {
    header: Header
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```